# How can I identify which device is which in my network just using my computer?

Tags: routing, packet-analysis

No engineer here, but I know some programming. I need to find out which device is which just using my computer. I tried using wireshark but since I only use windows 7 (don't ask but I can't use linux now) it seems it won't be possible because drivers matter. How can I filter my network's data to my computer or something similar so I know what device does what connections?

Comment: On your subnet all devices will arp at some point in time. Or you could use something like Zenmap for windows?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to ping the broadcast address of your network and then check the arp table of your computer (arp -a)
You can also try with nmap on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You could open a dosbox and run "netstat -na" and check established connections.